# How assign titles for each page by smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

i have alot of pages and i want assign title for each page how can id?

i assign home page but cannot assign pages. the variable will add in header.tpl

pages(contact.php,order.php,products.php)

i'm using {$hometitle}
$smarty->assign('hometitle',$hometitle);

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the question:
Does this help?

In your php:

```
<?php
  $smarty = new Smarty();
  $smarty->assign('hometitle',$hometitle);
  $smarty->display('index.tpl');
?>
```

In your templates:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{$hometitle}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--body content here-->
  </body>
</html>
```